# Magento 1.6 Installation with Sample Data "The page isn't redirecting properly"

Tags: magento

I m trying to install magento 1.6 with sample data but when I run the magento-sample-data-1.2.0.sql the magento setup can't complete, it takes too much time and at the end it display "The page isn't redirecting properly" Message.

Without sample database it install perfectly.

I install the sample sql script using sqlyog, then I start the magento installation.

I tried to replace the localhost with 127.0.0.1, rewrite_module is on, php safe mode is off, but still no luck.

I m using windows 7 32 bit, wammp 2.0, also tried with xampp 1.7

It install fine with magento 1.4, but on home page product, when I click on any product it shows:

```
Whoops, our bad...
The page you requested was not found, and we have a fine guess why.
If you typed the URL directly, please make sure the spelling is correct.
If you clicked on a link to get here, the link is outdated.
```

Somebody please tell the way to install it with sample data.

Thanks

Comment: I also tried to run the sample data script after but it show "proccess... page not found", and when I run the script in the middle it stuck the installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with Ubuntu.

You should reindex and this is all. (admin panel/System/Index Mana)

Answer (score 0):

If you have shell access I suggest you to use this shell commands:

```
wget http://www.magentocommerce.com/downloads/assets/1.6.0.0/magento-1.6.0.0.tar.gz;
wget http://www.magentocommerce.com/downloads/assets/1.2.0/magento-sample-data-1.2.0.tar.gz;
tar -zxf magento-1.6.0.0.tar.gz;
tar -zxf magento-sample-data-1.2.0.tar.gz;
mv magento-sample-data-1.2.0/media/* magento/media/;
mv magento-sample-data-1.2.0/magento_sample_data_for_1.2.0.sql magento/data.sql;
mv magento/* magento/.htaccess .;
chmod -R o+w media;
chmod o+w app/etc;
#mysql -h DBHOST -u DBUSER -pDBPASS DBNAME < data.sql;
rm -rf magento/ magento-sample-data-1.2.0/;
rm -rf magento-1.6.0.0.tar.gz magento-sample-data-1.2.0.tar.gz data.sql;
```

This script will download magento and sample data plus install sample data into database you specify. You need to remove comment and specify your host(if not localhost) user password and database. Example:

```
mysql -u user --password=pass dbname < data.sql
```

Comment: Thanks but I m using windows 7 32 bit

Comment: Ok then. How do you upload your data to MySql? Using phpyadmin? Try MysqlWorkbench. All in all the process is following: you load sample datato database, then install magento, and after installation you should do reindex. Well I suppose you could increase max_execution_time if during installation you are dropped from it.

Comment: I run sample_data.sql using sqlyog. yes It did the same, I also increased max_execution_time = 0 and input_time = 0

Comment: At what stage you are getting this "The page isn't redirecting properly" message? It might be that there are some connection problems with server or db. Try also to watch through logs.

Comment: Also you should restart apache to max_execution_time take place.

Comment: Yes I restarted it, and also restarted my machine, clear var folder when reinstalling

Comment: So at what stage you are getting this message?

Comment: I m getting it run magento setup, transition between Configuration and Create Admin Account

Comment: Well by configuration you mean database configuration? Well something strange, might be that application can't write app/etc/local.xml or for example you should test another session storage. Well, currently no ideas left :(

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and after long research found the cause of the issue & solution.

Cause of the issue: Add Store Code to Urls to Yes => If its Yes the MAGENTO URLs without Store Codes are specified in the third party services it won't work

Solution using Admin Panel:
Login to magento admin panel then system->config->General->Web-> Url options -> change "Add Store Code to Urls" SET to "No"

Solution using Magento database:
RUN this query: select * from core_config_data where path like '%url/use_store%';
then set value to 0

It will solve the redirect issue on frontend magento